# AudioFlinger server died. Play RTSP stream won't start on Lollipop device only.

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-5.0-lollipop, rtsp, libstreaming

I'm testing [libstreaming library](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming). My app description: One device stream video from camera to another device via RTSP. All working perfectly on KitKat devices but my Huawei p8 lite (Lollipop) can't run stream beacause:

> W/AudioSystem: AudioFlinger server died!
>
> W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
>
> E/MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
>
> E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)

My stream server side:

```
        // Configures the SessionBuilder
        SessionBuilder.getInstance()
                .setSurfaceView(surfaceView)
                .setPreviewOrientation(90)
                .setContext(getApplicationContext())
                .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_NONE)
                .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(16000, 32000))
                .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
                .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(320,240,20,500000));

        // Starts the RTSP server
        this.startService(new Intent(this,RtspServer.class));
```

Play stream side:

```
private void play() {
        if(mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        }
        setErrorListener();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        try {
            //RTSP SERVER URI
            String videoUri = "rtsp://192.168.1.1:8086?/";

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(videoUri));
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When lollipop device is streaming then kitkat device dont have any isuess to play stream. Why play stream not working on this particular device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.

For some reason url created with ( "?/" ) doesn't work on Lollipop:

```
String videoUri = "rtsp://192.168.1.1:8086?/";
```

Then I edit method `Parse();` in libstreaming. I removed the whole part about parameterization session using url.

And I changed `videoUri` to without (?):

```
String videoUri ="rtsp://192.168.1.1:8086/";
```